# Are commercial electrical questions on topic here?

Tags: discussion

Are non-residential electrical questions on topic here?  For example, [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/101297/33), which asks about wiring a showcase light. There are special codes that deal with this type of wiring, which would not be familiar to DIYers that do primarily residential electrical work.

Comment: [Should questions about building things that are not part of your home be on-topic?](http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/questions/290/should-questions-about-building-things-that-are-not-part-of-your-home-be-on-topi/301#301) It is after all a site for "contractors and serious DIYers". That being said, [For Safety's Sake, how do you answer an electrical question?](http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/questions/1029/for-safetys-sake-how-do-you-answer-an-electrical-question?rq=1)

Answer (score 6):

In the past, we've considered commercial questions off topic, but allowing them if they were relevant to residential uses. I feel this is a good approach going forward since there's a limited pool of talent on the site that would know answers to commercial questions, and people asking these questions should really be hiring a professional as a cost of doing business.

Regarding the specific question being linked to above, I suspect an answer that doesn't get into commercial code requirements would help the OP and others in a residential environment equally. The standard "check your local codes" disclaimer would cover any concern of the OP doing work that may require a licensed electrician. So I lean towards leaving it open.